# Import Excel with vue and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, excel, laravel, vue.js

can you help me to import excel into my program? i use `maatwebsite/excel` for uploading excel file.

So, i have

**BarangController.php**

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    // $path = $request->file('excel')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($request->file('excel'))->get();

     if($data->count()){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $arr[] = ['nama_barang' => $value->nama_barang];
        }

        if(!empty($arr)){
            return $arr;
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.vue (modal)**

```
              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input @change="uploadExcel" id="excel" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
                  <label class="custom-file-label" for="excel">{{ fileName }}</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button @click="importExcel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-left">Import</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
              </div>
```

**Index.vue (methods js)**

```
importExcel() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.import.post('/api/barang/import').then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data);
        this.$Progress.finish();
      }).catch(() => {
        this.$Progress.fail();
      })
    },
    uploadExcel(e) {
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();

      // console.log(file);
      if(file['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") {
        this.fileName = file['name'];
        //this.import.excel = file;
        reader.onloadend = (file) => {
          this.import.excel = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        //this.import.excel = file;
        console.log(this.import.excel);
      } else {
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'warning',
          title: 'Format file salah'
        })
      }
    },
```

And when i check in console log its not get an array result for excel, i hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if you directly `return $data = Excel::load($request->file('excel'))->get();` in your import method of your controller? What does your console say then?

Comment: json with config, data, headers, etc keys, i trying to get data key with $data->data is not work

Comment: What does your excel file look like?

Comment: Class 'Vtiful\Kernel\Excel' not found